# Does a decreasing shape factor correspond to greater or reduced probability of separation?

Tags: aerodynamics, stall, turbulence

The shape factor ($H=\frac{\delta^*}{\theta}$) is the ratio of displacement thickness, a measure of the thickness of the boundary layer, to the momentum thickness, a measure of the shear stress. I think that a larger shape factor indicates that the boundary layer is larger and there is less shear stress, so it seems like a larger shape factor should be associated with a greater likelihood of separation. Is that right? If not, why?

Comment: There is no need to close this question. It is very clear what OP is asking.

Comment: @Koyovis It might be that I used the separation tag wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're reasoning is spot on. As the momentum thickness decreases, that indicates the velocity gradient at the wall is less, indicating a greater likelihood of separation occurring.

Comment: If you answer your own question, more explanation and background is useful.